# Are Thom spectra MU, MSO and K-theory spectra KU, KO modules over some truncations of the sphere spectrum?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cobordism, ring-spectra, stable-homotopy, higher-category-theory

The Thom spectrum MO is a module over the ring spectrum π<sub>≤0</sub>S=H**Z**, where S is the sphere spectrum.
In particular, MO is equivalent to the Eilenberg-MacLane spectrum Hπ<sub>*</sub>(MO).
On the other hand, MU and MSO are not modules over π<sub>≤0</sub>S, because they have nontrivial k-invariants.

I wonder if the above result about MO can be generalized to other Thom spectra like MU and MSO
by considering higher truncations π<sub>≤k</sub>S of the sphere spectrum.
Such a result would be interesting because it is related to the question of representing Thom spectra
as (weak) simplicial objects in the k-category of symmetric monoidal (k+1)-groups (k-groupoids with invertible objects), in the sense that
interpreting symmetric monoidal (k+1)-groups as stable homotopy k-types and taking the homotopy colimit should give back the Thom spectrum under consideration.
Such models are interesting because they are more strict then (say) Segal's Γ-spaces.
A negative answer would necessarily preclude the existence of such models because a stable homotopy k-type
is a module over π<sub>≤k</sub>S, and the homotopy colimit of a simplicial diagram of modules over π<sub>≤k</sub>S in the category of spectra is a again a module over π<sub>≤k</sub>S.

**Is MU or MSO a module over the ring spectrum π<sub>≤k</sub>S for some k>0?  Same question for KU and KO.**

(Incidentally, the above result for MO implies that MO can be represented as a simplicial abelian group.
I wonder if there is a geometric model for MO as a simplicial abelian group along the lines of Galatius-Madsen-Tillmann-Weiss theorem,
i.e., n-simplices should be related to unoriented n-manifolds.
Such a model would necessarily make explicit use of properties of unoriented manifolds as opposed to oriented or stably complex manifolds.)

Comment: I would be very surprised if this worked for $MU$. 

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For any $k$ and any $0<n<\infty$, $K(n)\wedge \pi_{\leq k}S=0$.  Indeed, this is true for any spectrum with finitely many homotopy groups, since $K(n)\wedge H\mathbb{Z}=0$ and any such spectrum has a finite filtration into Eilenberg-MacLane spectra.  If a spectrum $M$ admits a $\pi_{\leq k}S$-module structure, then $M$ is a retract of $\pi_{\leq k}S\wedge M$, and so $K(n)\wedge M$ is a retract of $K(n)\wedge\pi_{\leq k}S\wedge M=0$ and hence $K(n)\wedge M=0$.  But this is not true for $n=1$ and all of your examples (for $MSO$, you must work at an odd prime).

Comment: Very nice, thanks a lot.  Can this argument be extended to the more general case of (not necessarily group-like) E_∞-spaces, as opposed to connective spectra?  In other words, can MU, MSO, KU, or KO be represented as a homotopy colimit of k-truncated E_∞-spaces in the ∞-category of E_∞-spaces for some k?