# Which E_∞-spaces are homotopy colimits of k-truncated E_∞-spaces?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, operads, limits-and-colimits, homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory

This question is closely related to my [previous question about modules over truncated sphere spectra](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/124352), in particular, it has the same motivation.

Recall that every space (or ∞-groupoid) can be represented as the homotopy colimit of some simplicial diagram of 0-truncated spaces, i.e., sets considered as homotopy 0-types.
For example, if X is a Kan simplicial set, then the homotopy colimit of X considered as a functor X: Δ<sup>op</sup> → Set → Space is equivalent to X itself.

For connective spectra (i.e., group-like E<sub>∞</sub>-spaces) a more complicated picture emerges:
homotopy colimits of simplicial diagrams of 0-truncated connective spectra (i.e., abelian groups) are precisely Eilenberg-MacLane spectra (of connective chain complexes of abelian groups).
More generally, homotopy colimits of simplicial diagrams of k-truncated connective spectra for some k>0 are modules over
the k-truncation π<sub>≤k</sub>S of the sphere spectrum S.
In particular, not every connective spectrum can be represented in this way.
(Presumably, being a module over π<sub>≤k</sub>S is also a sufficient condition, but I haven't checked any details to claim this.)

I wonder what happens in the intermediate case of (not necessarily group-like) E<sub>∞</sub>-spaces.

**Which E<sub>∞</sub>-spaces can be represented as homotopy colimits of k-truncated E<sub>∞</sub>-spaces for some k>0?  What if we require the diagrams to be simplicial, i.e., indexed by Δ<sup>op</sup>?**

In particular, if some E<sub>∞</sub>-spaces cannot be represented in this way, what tools do we have to detect this?

Specifically, I'm interested in the answer for the case of E<sub>∞</sub>-spaces coming from connective spectra like MU, MSO, KU, or KO.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, and didn't know the answer to the previous one either. But both times I thought of Goodwillie Calculus. Have you learned much about that subject? It seems to be valuable when trying to realize things as (ho)colimits of towers of truncated versions, and I feel like I've seen that machinery applied to $E_\infty$ things before. Just some idle speculation.

Comment: Taking homotopy colimits of 0-truncated connective spectra gives you much more than just Eilenberg-MacLane spectra.  For instance, it includes all 1-connective spectra with finitely many homotopy groups, because you can build them by repeatedly taking cofibers of maps from connective Eilenberg-MacLane spectra.

Comment: @Eric Wolfsey: I had in mind diagrams indexed by Δ^op, similarly to the first example.  I edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you don't group complete, then free $E_{\infty}$-spaces are $1$-truncated.
Consequently, for $k > 0$, the answer is "all $E_{\infty}$-spaces". When $k=0$, you'll
get those which are homotopy equivalent to simplicial commutative monoids.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!  Is this result still true if we insist that all diagrams for homotopy colimits are simplicial, i.e., indexed by Δ^op?

Comment: @Dmitri: I believe that one way to see this is to use hypercovers. Namely, given an $E_\infty$-space $X$, choose a free one $F$ (on a discrete set) with a map $F \to X$ which is a surjection on $\pi_0$. Now form the fiber product $F \times_X F$ and choose an free $E_\infty$-space (on a discrete set) $F'$ with a map $F' \to F \times_X F$ inducing a surjection on $\pi_0$. This is a small piece of a simplicial resolution for $X$. Repeating this process, you get a simplicial $E_\infty$-space whose geometric realization is $X$. 